# Java: Using Dynamically loaded classes

Tags: java, reflection, class, dynamic, load

I'm new to java.
I'm trying to use some dynamically loaded classes in my application.
The application doesn't know classes , Just it try to load a class by name that its name came from input.
It doesn't know class (So I can't use casting) but just needs to call some methods of that class (every class should have that methods).
I thought about interfaces but I don't know how.
How can I call those methods?

Thanks

Comment: can you illustrate what you mean with examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class.

```
   public InterfaceType getDynamicClass(String className) {
       return (InterfaceType) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
   }
```

The interface is to ensure that the methods  exists. Of course, you'll have to watch out for the exceptions and handle them appropriately for your application.

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
Class k = loadMyClassDynamically();
```

you can

```
Method m = k.getDeclaredMethod("methodName", ArgClass1.class, ArgClass2.class);
```

Then, if you create an instance of k

```
Object ki = k.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

you can call the method on `ki`

```
m.invoke(ki, ArgClass3.class, ArgClass4.class);
```

See [the reflection tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll want to use either interfaces or then a base class from which you inherit. This way you can call a predefined set of methods of the objects you're creating at run-time.

And to get that far you'll probably have to use reflection to create instances based on (text?) input.

Comment: Yeah, i concur with tylermac ;)